# Are XML attributes compulsory?

Tags: android, ios, xml

I wanted to know if xml attributes are compulsory. Let me illustrate with an example.

```
<myxml>
    <myelement attr1="value1" attr2="value2" />
    <myelement attr1="value3" />
</myxml>
```

Will this XML be parsed by most of the XML parsers? I'm mostly interested in knowing whether XML parsers in-built in iOS and Android SDKs will parse this XML correctly and whether parsing will be more difficult for those guys?

Please excuse if this question is a partial repetition of any earlier question, but I needed a definitive answer for this.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: ??? If you are interested in whether it will be parsed correctly or not then why not give it a try yourself?  "More difficult" for what?  This question shows little effort...

Comment: "Herd mentality" and "trigger-happy" are 2 words I can think of for you guys. I just wanted to ensure that the XML schema I hand out to my client's developers are parsable by them. Downvotes my foot!!!

Comment: Usually, xml comes with a schema/description. often a DTD for instance. this schema indicates which attributes and nodes are mandatory.

Comment: also, most modern parsers have a validator integrated that will allow you to check the validity of the xml against a dtd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XML attributes are not compulsory. You use it according to your own convinience and need. Yes this XML will be parsed with all of the parsers. If at all the XML is valid then it will be parsed by any XML parser correctly whether it be in iOS or Android.